# Postgresql Json performance

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL. I have a dataset which have 125K of following Json (similar):

```
{"data_type": "PDE", "data_format": "MITRE", "data_version": "4.0", "PDE_data_meta": {"ID": "PDE-0001", "ASSIGNER": "PDE@xs2.org"}, "problemtype": {"problemtype_data": [{"description": [{"lang": "en", "value": "CWE-20"}]}]}, "references": {"reference_data": [{"url": "http://www.example.com ", "name": "http://www.example.com ", "refsource": "CONFIRM", "tags": []}, {"url": "http://www.example.com", "name": "5707", "refsource": "OSVDB", "tags": []}]}, "description": {"description_data": [{"lang": "en", "value": "asd"}]}}
```

I splitted them and created following table:

```
 CREATE TABLE public.vu
(
    "ID" integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    PDE json,
    "PDE_ID" text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    PDE_published boolean,
    PDE_references jsonb,
    PDE_impact jsonb,
    PDE_cwe text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    PDE_valid boolean,
    PDE_published_date date,
    PDE_eval_has_ex boolean,
    PDE_vu_products_has_inc_excl boolean,
    PDE_vu_products jsonb,
    PDE_description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    CONSTRAINT vu_pkey PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
```

Some Json entries contain up to 500 elements in a node (e.g. PDE_vu_products). I thought it will be easier if save it as Json in my table.

I have another dataset. There are 15M products in this dataset and i have to check if these products are in the table VU (in column PDE_vu_products).

I don't want to use normalized column (text). Then i have to parse all json and make too many columns, tables.

Is that a good idea? If i save my data so as i described above?

And content of PDE_vu_products:

```
[ {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.0:releng:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.4:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.5:stable:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.5.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.5.1:release:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:3.5.1:stable:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.0:alpha:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.0:releng:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.1.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.1.1:release:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.1.1:stable:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.2:stable:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.3:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.3:release:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.3:release_p38:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.3:releng:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.3:stable:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.4:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.4:release_p42:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.4:releng:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.4:stable:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.5:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.5:release:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.5:release_p32:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.5:releng:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.5:stable:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.6:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.6:release:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.6:release_p20:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.6:releng:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.6:stable:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.6.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.7:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.7:release:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.7:release_p17:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.7:releng:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.7:stable:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.8:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.8:pre-release:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.8:release_p6:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.8:releng:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.9:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:4.9:pre-release:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:5.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:5.0:alpha:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:5.0:release_p14:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:5.0:releng:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:5.1:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:5.1:release_p5:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:5.1:releng:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        }, {
          "active" : true,
          "cpe23Uri" : "cpe:2.3:o:freebsd:freebsd:5.2:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
        } ]
```

Comment: In General `jsonb` is recommended over `json`

Comment: Yes, it's easy to convert it in table schema. The question is if it's a good idea, insert json and then make the analyse...

Comment: The important question is: how do you need to query the data?

Comment: i plan to do it in python

Comment: Your example json doesn't contain example vu_products section, so that makes it hard to offer much advice.  But it looks like you have already broken the JSON document down into at least 4 different json columns.  Why do that that much, if you don't want to finish the process of normalizing it?  For performance it will probably be better to use JSONB, not JSON.  Everytime the database needs to inspect JSON, it need to re-parse it, which can be slow.

Comment: okey i added the content of PDE_vu_products.

Comment: As long as you don't expect the '*' to represent wildcards, you should be able to index this for fast containment queries with @>.

Comment: how can I do that?